# How to load all data in Details Report using Toggl API with PHP?

Tags: php, api

In one of my client's application I'm using **Toggl API** with **PHP**. In where I need to load all data, i.e: client, project, user, task, start time, end time, etc using **Detail Report**.

Everything is OK, but it loads only 50 rows!! But I need to load all available rows. Can anyone tell me how can I do load all the rows in **Details Report** using **Toggle API**?

I'm using [This Toggl PHP API](https://github.com/Morning-Train/toggl-api) and here is my code for **Details Report**:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$report = new MorningTrain\TogglApi\TogglReportsApi('my_api_token');
$workspaceId = work_space_id;
$data = $report->getDetailsReport(array('user_agent'=>'test_apps', 'workspace_id'=> $workspaceId));
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix my code to load all data?

- Thanks

Comment: How about get a list of projects/clients and iterate over them in order to get detailed data for each one?